# Crop an ellipse form from an image instead of drawing it inside in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a rectangle that I want to extract the ellipse form of it from a given image. My code looks like:

```
RotatedRect ellipse ;
float p1 = (float) rect.width/2 + rect.x;
float p2 = (float) rect.height/2 + rect.y;
CvPoint2D32f p = cvPoint2D32f(p1,p2);
ellipse.center = p;
ellipse.angle = 0;
ellipse.size =  cvSize2D32f((float)rect.width, (float)rect.height);
ellipse( image_colored, minEllipse, CV_RGB(255,255,255), 2, 8 );
```

The input of this code are: an image (image_colored) and CvRect (rect). The last line of code, draws a white ellipse inside the "image_colored", but I am looking to crop the generated ellipse in an other image or just color the rest of the image in black.

Any help, will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

PS: I can not use the function cvEllipse(...) as it was suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207147/opencv-crop-image-with-ellipse).
Because cvEllipse does not accept an object of type CvPoint2D32f, neither CvSize2D32f type.

Comment: "I can not use the function cvEllipse(...) as it was suggested" -- that's ok. stick with the c++ api for the better. avoid any cv*functions or structures from the deprecated c-api

Answer (score 2):

Make an image with a filled ellipse and use this as a mask combined (bitwise and) with your image [OpenCV bitwise_and + mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532924/opencv-bitwise-and-mask/11670190#11670190) or [Segmenting Lungs and nodules in CT images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285200/segmenting-lungs-and-nodules-in-ct-images/20288616#20288616)

Comment: +1 That's it. I also demonstrate how to use this technique in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20288616/176769).

Comment: @karlphillip, thanks search didn't turn up your title!